# Сон после нажатия клавиши питания

Tags: linux, debian

Установил Debian Jessie на ноутбук. Чтобы отправлять ноутбук в сон (suspend), начал пытаться править файлы в `/etc/acpi` (включая поддиректорию `/events`), используя многочисленные советы из Google. В конечном итоге пришел к следующему поведению: при нажатии клавиши питания ноутбук уходит в сон, но, если снова ее нажать, ноутбук включается и... сразу выключается.

Уход в сон удалось задать файлом `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` со следующим содержанием:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

---

Вопрос: как заставить ноутбук уходить в сон по нажатию на кнопку питания и выходить из него без выключения (как сейчас)?

---

**UPD_0** (удалил второй блок с файлами из-за потери актуальности):

Я создал для файлов `powerbtn.sh`, `powerbtn-acpi-support.sh`, `events/powerbtn` и `events/powerbtn-acpi-support` вывод о своем запуске в файл и выяснил следующее: файлы в папке `/etc/acpi/` - не используются, а используются только файлы из `/etc/acpi/events/`.

Файл ***`events/powerbtn`***:

```
event=button[ /]power
action=sh /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn-log.sh
```

Файл ***`events/powerbtn-log.sh`***:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "events/powerbtn" >> /home/rostislav/log.txt
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

Файл ***`events/powerbtn-acpi-support`***:

```
event=button[ /]power
action=sh /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn-acpi-support-log.sh
```

Файл ***`events/powerbtn-acpi-support-log.sh`***:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "events/powerbtn-acpi-support" >> /home/rostislav/log.txt
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

Вывод в лог:

```
events/powerbtn-acpi-support
events/powerbtn
```

И возникает проблема: почему после выполнения `powerbtn-acpi-support` не перезапускается компьютер?

---

**UPD_1**: еще один парадокс. Если удалить любой файл из `events/powerbtn-acpi-support` или `events/powerbtn` - перезагрузка перестает работать!

Comment: я не разбираюсь во всех этих событиях, и не знаю, что там и как должно работать. но если внесённые вами изменения привели к изменениям в поведении системы, то, с большой долей вероятности, именно ваши изменения послужили этому причиной.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, до меня система, как минимум, не переходила в сон. Осталось понять, в чем причина выключения...

Comment: Простите, не улавливаю вашу мысль во втором предложении: "Чтобы отправлять ноутбук в сон, начал пытаться файлы".

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, случайно удалил часть предложения. Исправил.

Comment: Без модели ноутбука и версии ядра тяжело что-либо советовать, может быть баг в софте, а может и в ваших скриптах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ноутбук выключается потому что два демона следят за кнопкой. Один это acpid, который Вы настроили, а второй это systemd.

Происходит следующее:
При нажатии кнопки systemd начинает завершение работы, а acpid в этот момент уводит комп в сон. При пробуждении завершение работы возобновляется.

Systemd настраивается тут /etc/systemd/logind.conf

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=hibernate
HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=hybrid-sleep
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
#UserTasksMax=33%
```

Как тут видно я настроил гибернацию на закрытие крышки. Тут можно отключить обработку кнопок. Или убирайте Ваши скрипты и настройте тут.

В Gnome через `gnome-tweak-tool` (или `gnome-control-center` в поздних версиях) можно переопределить действия на нажатие кнопки.
После входа в систему Гном перенастроит systemd на указанное поведение.